# Double plusses in regex

Tags: php, regex

I have seen several regular expressions that have two plusses in a row.  What exactly does this mean? One or more of one or more of the pattern.  If the pattern matches in the first place, why would the second match be necessary?

Examples:

```
[a-zA-Z0-9_]++
[^/.,;?]++
```

Answer (score 5):

They're called [possessive quantifiers](http://www.regular-expressions.info/possessive.html).